# Why run JIRA in JBoss?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, jira, servlet

I've just finished getting JIRA & Confluence up and running Tomcat on Ubuntu Server when I noticed on the web there were installation instructions for JIRA/Confluence on JBoss.

I am unfamiliar with JEE applications servers, having spent most of my time with simpler servlet containers.

However, assuming that JIRA does not make use of EJB's, why would one deploy it to JBoss?  What does JBoss provide in this instance that Tomcat doesn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason is that some organizations standardize on a particular application server and insist that all Java application run on that application server.

Another reason would be that the person installing Jira may be more comfortable working with JBoss than Tomcat.

There is no advantage to running Jira in JBoss and the performance may be slower if the JBoss instance that is running Jira is not optimized.